# Render ASP.NET TextBox as HTML5 Input type "Number"

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox

When an ASP.NET TextBox renders it produces:

```
<input type="text" />
```

However I need it to render as a HTML5 number type instead, like:

```
<input type="number" />
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I had the same requirement for a mobile website using ASP.NET. After finding no good solution, I tried simply setting `type="number"` directly on the textbox. To my surprise, it worked! Incredulous, I created a simple test project to double-check. I ran this line of code in each .NET version:

```
<!-- this HTML tested in each .NET version -->
<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="number" />
```

Here are the results:

```
<!-- ASP.NET 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 -->
<input name="ctl01" type="text" type="number" />

<!-- ASP.NET 4.0 and 4.5 -->
<input name="ctl01" type="number" />
```

Bottom line: if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 or newer, just add `type="number"` to your textbox.

Comment: @gunwin, It sounds like you pasted one of the result lines into your editor, in which case there would be duplicate `type` attributes. I've edited the answer to be more clear what I did in my tests.

Answer (score 18):

The [`TextMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode) property is used for that, e.g.,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="uPhone" CssClass="formEntry" TextMode="Phone" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

might be rendered as

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uPhone" id="uPhone" class="formEntry" type="tel">
```

The textmodes in addition to [ MultiLine | Password | SingleLine ] were introduced some time after VS2010 - the documentation does not quickly tell me exactly when.

Comment: This is "technically" the correct way to handle it now it is supported.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the members of the Enum  TextBoxMode

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyAwesomeId" runat="server" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
```

This render

```
<input type="number" value="5" id="MainContent_MyAwesomeId" c>
```

the full Enum is

```
public enum TextBoxMode
{
    SingleLine = 0,
    MultiLine = 1,
    Password = 2,
    Color = 3,
    Date = 4,
    DateTime = 5,
    DateTimeLocal = 6,
    Email = 7,
    Month = 8
    Number = 9,
    Range = 10,
    Search = 11,
    Phone = 12,
    Time = 13,
    Url = 14,
    Week = 15
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Override the base textbox control

```
public class HTML5TextBox : TextBox
{
.....
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
//Sth like the code below, you need do some research though
 writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type,"Number");
 writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, ClientID + "_displayTXT");
 writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name,this.UniqueID + "t1");
 writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value,base.Text);
 writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);       
 writer.RenderEndTag(); 
}
....
}
```

Or you can check the one I just found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68834/Enhanced-Textbox-Control

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this with a dynamically created control like this:

```
TextBox control = new TextBox();
control.Attributes.Add("Type", "number");
```

Answer (score 2):

you would have to create a new control inheriting from `TextBox` and override the rendering, or you can generate a javascript snippet to change it after the fact.

Comment: I've tried changing the type using jQuery, but this isn't working. http://jsfiddle.net/C4EYR/ 

Is this what you meant?

Comment: yeah, but it looks like jquery produces an error. doing it with vanilla javascript seems to work, at least in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/2vEKR/

Answer (score 1):

set `type="number"` in `<asp:textbox type="number" runat="server">`
regardless of that it's not appearing in the list, surprisely it will work