# How to render number input control with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm coding with VS2010 and I'm wondering what is the way to make my ASP.NET project render something as simple as this?

```
<input type="number">
```

Comment: @Kenneth: Hmm. You're right... I had no idea that it's so complicated though. I guess `ASP.NET != HTML5` :)

Comment: Another option is to switch to ASP.NET 4.5 which allows different TextModes: http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/11/28/new-html-5-input-types-in-asp-net-4-5.aspx

Comment: There's a patch for 4.0, or upgrade to 4.5 (as @Kenneth said).

Comment: @TimMedora: Do I need to get another VS license to get that patch?

Comment: Nope: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2011/08/10/html-5-updates-for-net-4.aspx

Comment: @TimMedora: Do you want to post it as a separate answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create control based on `TextBox` control and override it's `Render` method. Or you can render normal text `input` and later change the type to `number` with JavaScript. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398356/render-asp-net-textbox-as-html5-input-type-number) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

in code:

```
LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl(@"<input type='number'/>");
Page.Controls.Add(literal);
```

in aspx just:

```
<input type="number"/>
```

and browser which works with html5 will work fine, chrome does

Comment: Haha. Thanks. This is using code-behind. But would still work. It will just look confusing in a form designer though.

Comment: And you need to put @ in front of your string there...