# Change input type="text" to input type="password" onfocus()

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms, textbox

So far I have accomplished the 1st part, I successfully change the input type from text to password with this javascript:

```
function replaceT(obj) {
        var newO = document.createElement('input');
        newO.setAttribute('type', 'password');
        newO.setAttribute('class', 'textbox');
        newO.setAttribute('name', obj.getAttribute('name'));
        obj.parentNode.replaceChild(newO, obj);
        newO.focus();
    }
```

and ASP code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" SkinID="txtLogin" value="Password..." TabIndex="2" onfocus="replaceT(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

What I want is the second part. How to return the "*Password...*" value onblur.

In short, I want to implement a facebook-like password textbox. A **placeholder** attribute that function on IE.

Here how it goes before `focus()`:

[image]

then after focus:

[image]

then return to this `onblur()`:

[image]

Thank you.

P.S.

I want to implement this without jQuery(pure javascript) and I am working with IE 7+.

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. Please give a clean title and elaborate explanation of what you want.

Comment: You can achieve this using a simple background image. YOu don't have to change the type. Onfocus just remove the bg image and on blur if there is no content then just add the bg image.

Comment: HTML5 format na @ChristianMark?

Comment: best way is to use watemark api which help you more

Comment: Actually I knew about Watermark. But the problem is when I try to put a null/empty string value on the textbox simply didn't work.

Comment: @loy, yup. I think so.

Comment: what your are looking for is placeholder attribute.
then, you can use a polyfill (there are plenty of them https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) some with and some without jquery.

Comment: Can you elaborate more. or give at least an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to replace the component, just set the `type` of the `this` to `password` like the code below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" SkinID="txtLogin" value="Password..." TabIndex="2" onfocus="this.type='password'">
```

Here is a jsfiddle working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mZyTG/

**Update**

I didn't test this code, but it add one `onblur` event listener to newO, and when invoked it replace the input to the old one.

```
function replaceT(obj) {
        var newO = document.createElement('input');
        newO.setAttribute('type', 'password');
        newO.setAttribute('class', 'textbox');
        newO.setAttribute('name', obj.getAttribute('name'));
        newO.addEventListener("onblur", function(){newO.parentNode.replaceChild(obj, newO)}, false);
        obj.parentNode.replaceChild(newO, obj);
        newO.focus();
    }
```

Comment: I actually got the 1st question. I achieve this by replacing the element. Since I am also working on IE, what you did is not compatible to IE.

Comment: got it now, your question wasn't clear... the problem by replacing is that I think it will lose the "integration" with the component generated by the asp

Comment: I would suggest you a different solution... generate 2 TextBox using the asp, one will be text tupe and another password type... so when click the text type you hide it and show the password type one

Comment: @ChristianMark I updated it with one solution, which might work in the browser but not sure if you will be able to get the value of this field in the asp server

Comment: Hey @ChristianMark..this is from my friend of mine *davidwalsh*.he uses placeholder html5... check this out:http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" SkinID="txtLogin" value="Password..."placeholder="Enter your password" >
```

just place this code in your asp section no need of javascript
hope this helps

edit 2:hope this helps,tested with ie 10

```
 <html>
 <script>
 function a()
{
document.getElementById("p1").value="";
document.getElementById("p1").type="password";

}

function b()
{
if(document.getElementById("p1").value=="")
{
document.getElementById("p1").type="text";
document.getElementById("p1").value="Password";
}
else
{   
document.getElementById("p1").type="password";

}


}
</script>
<body>
Password:<input type="text" value="Password" onclick="a();" id="p1"         

onblur="b();">
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ie7` wont support placeholder

Comment: Hi @Ritesh, I tried your solution and it worked on IE 9 and 10. However, I need to make it work on IE 7 and 8. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try this small plugin

```
 <script>
   $(".contentplaceholder").placeholderContent();
 </script>
```

Check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/VdtBs/

Check the new fiddle for pure javascript place holder

http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/VdtBs/2/

Comment: Is this running with jQuery?

Comment: *I want to implement this without jQuery(pure javascript) and I am working with IE 7+.* :)

Comment: Thank you for the effort though.

Comment: Check the new fiddle
i have updated with pure javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/VdtBs/2/

Answer (score 0):

I will start with an advice to separate your javascript and css from your markup. It considered as old school and to be a bad practice nowadays. There are some known issues with setAttribute and getAttribute in IE and since it probably important to you i would try to use something else. Try to google it: [issues with setAttribute and getAttribute in ie](https://www.google.de/search?q=issues%20with%20setAttribute%20and%20getAttribute%20in%20ie&oq=issues%20with%20setAttribute%20and%20getAttribute%20in%20ie&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.13887j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I made something in jsfiddle, i hope it works for you, if not - let me know. Code snippet: [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/PgGJ3/).

**HTML**

```
<input class='placeholder' value="Type here..."/>
```

**CSS**

```
.placeholder {
    color: #aaa; 
}
.text {
    color: #000;
}
```

**JS**

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

if(input.addEventListener) {
    input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
        this.type = 'text' 
        this.value = 'Type here...';
        this.className = 'placeholder';
    }, false);
    input.addEventListener('focus', function(){
        this.type = 'password'
        this.value = '';
        this.className = 'text';
    }, false);
} else if(input.attachEvent) {
    input.attachEvent('onblur', function(){
        this.type = 'text' 
        this.value = 'Type here...';
        this.className = 'placeholder';
    });
    input.attachEvent('onfocus', function(){
        this.type = 'password'
        this.value = '';
        this.className = 'text';
    });
}
```

Accessing elements by id would make it more specific and faster but accessing elements by tag name would allow you to apply the same code for all input elements with help of loop.

It should work although i'm using linux and haven't time to test it in ie.

My example applied only to your specific task, i would recommend you to make a function out of it to make it applicable to wider area of tasks.

**EDIT:** For newer browsers i would go with [placeholder attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder). Here is the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder)

Comment: Can you update your answer and make it compatible with this field:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" SkinID="txtLogin" value="Password..." TabIndex="2" onfocus="replaceT(this)"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: @ChristianMark every serverside language will be translated to simple html before it receives the client. Since JS runs in the browser it does make the code above valid even in your example.  I also found that ASP TextBox will be rendered as `<input type=text/>` that's why i don't see any reason why you couldn't use my code. There is also what might interest you:[how to change a rendered element or at least its type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398356/render-asp-net-textbox-as-html5-input-type-number)