# asp:TextBox not responding to type Number?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, input

I have the following code in my html:

```
<asp:TextBox id="quantity" runat="server" type="number" pattern="[0-9]" />
```

And it seems to render in the browser as

```
<input name="quantity" id="quantity" type="text" pattern="[0-9]" >
```

and not

```
<input name="quantity" id="quantity" type="number" pattern="[0-9]" >
```

I'm not sure what the cause of this issue could be but this was working correctly at some stage. Any idea what might cause this to happen?

Comment: Have you installed HTML 5 update for server controls: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2468871/update-for-the--net-framework-4-march--2011? If the page currently uses HTML 5 the `type` attribute should work in `TextBox` server control.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398356/render-asp-net-textbox-as-html5-input-type-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon testing I'm noticing that when the .Net target framework for the solution is set to 3.5 `type="number"` will render as `type="text"`. However, in later frameworks ( I tested on 4.5 ) it seems that the type is rendered correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the onkeydown Property of the TextBox for limiting its value to numbers only..

Very easy..:-)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeydown = "return (!(event.keyCode>=65) && event.keyCode!=32);"></asp:TextBox>
```

`!(keyCode>=65)` check is for excludng the Albphabets..

`keyCode!=32` check is for excluding the Space character inbetween the numbers.